# Counting rows from multiple table and print result in ascending order using python

Tags: python

I have four tables in my database and I want to print the result of each table in ascending order. Is there any intelligent and simple way of doing this? So far my code is similar to this:

```
nr0 = TotalNrOfRows0
nr1 = TotalNrOfRows1
if nr0 > nr1:
    print 'use nr0'
else:
    print 'use nr1'
```

My question is how about if I have ten list of table how am I going to print this in ascending order? I am not really sure if the if statement is a good way for selecting table with the highest row? I might probably just select all table using:

```
tableListQuery = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY Name"
```

But instead of using order by name, I should order by row? Any suggestion?

Comment: Difficult to answer without the database schema but it's very likely doing this ordering at the database level would be faster than trying to let Python do it (even if it was more difficult to code).

Comment: I agree with @Two-BitAlchemist. If you must order lists, you can use [sorted with lambdas](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)